# How do I make Character(SCNNode) bounce off of a wall in Scenekit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to make a simple maze game in Scenekit. I have a sphere node and wall nodes. The sphere moves by SCNActions. The actions I use on the sphere are moveByX actions. My problem is that whenever the sphere hits a wall, it just moves the wall back with it. My sphere is kinematic and my walls are dynamic. I don't have any forces in the scene, only my moveByX actions. How can I make it so my sphere bounces off of the walls?

I am using Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Change walls to .static and sphere to .dynamic

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it would be to have variables for xSpeed and ySpeed, and whenever you collide with a wall make the corresponding variable negative. This is a pretty basic approach and doesn't take diagonal walls into account.

For example:

```
var xSpeed = 5.0 var ySpeed = 5.0

if collision with wall in x direction { xSpeed = -xSpeed }

if collision with wall in y direction { ySpeed = -ySpeed }
```

It might be a bit tricky to detect the collisions, you might have to look up some tutorials on SpriteKit collisions.

Comment: I am using scenekit and I don't fully understand what u mean by this? Do u mean to have the xSpeed and ySpeed move the character back on collision?

Comment: My mistake, didn't notice you were using SceneKit, hopefully this can still help. When you call moveByX, fill in xSpeed and ySpeed for the parameters.

Comment: I'll try that out. Thanks! And is there really no simple way to stop characters when they hit walls and make them bounce off? Dang, Apple should really make it easier to stop actions with walls!!!

Comment: Well Apple has made a pretty good physics simulator, not sure how easy it would be to implement it using SceneKit or how well it would suit your needs, but that might be worth looking into as well.

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift3**

```
    let border  = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 1

    self.physicsBody = border
```